# How to invoke QueryPagination in dart? AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, datastore, aws-amplify

I'm using Amplify with flutter, I wanna write a query and limit the data being queried, I looked into the documentation https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/flutter#pagination and found this code snippet:
List posts = await Amplify.DataStore.query(Post.classType,
pagination: new QueryPagination(page:0, limit:100));
But unlike the snippet I'm not able to invoke QueryPagination to feed data into page and limit attributes, I viewed the source of pagination attribute of query and found that QueryPagination class is defined but I don't know how to invoke it.

[Issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrT6w.png)

Thank you for reading, please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having the same issue this should help you out: try importing manually:
import 'package:amplify_datastore_plugin_interface/amplify_datastore_plugin_interface.dart';, I found the solution here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/500

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue.

import

```
 import 'package:amplify_datastore/amplify_datastore.dart';
```

or

```
import 'package:amplify_datastore_plugin_interface/amplify_datastore_plugin_interface.dart';
```

if the issue still persists, then restart your IDE. This was the solution that eventually worked for me.